# Appending a button using Javascript without using the createElement method

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
    var i=0;
    var j="";
    function app() {
        j+=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="<button type='button'>Btn+i</button>";
   }
</script>  
<button type="button" onclick="app()">Add</button>
<div id="demo">
</div>
```

I am trying to append a **button** in the `div` tag every time user clicks add button.

> Also I want the **added button** to be displayed like : Btn 1, Btn2,
>   Btn3..

Comment: What's so bad about the `createElement` method?

Comment: Im just trying something new? Idk. Just wondering if it can be done how im trying to do it.

Comment: Oh that's fine  just wondering if there was any reason, as in if there's like a setback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple concatenation of `#demo` content and incrementation of a var `i`:

```js
var i = 0;

function app() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<button type='button'>Btn " +
    ++i + "</button>";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="app()">Add</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Can you please explain why we add "+=" after innerHTML ?

Comment: It's a concatenation operator in this case. It will add the new html button to the existing ones instead of overwritting them. @ShonAufdaded

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `.innerHtml` **+=** ...

And increase `i`

```js
var i=0;
function app()
{
j+=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+="<button type='button'>        Btn"+i+"</button>";
i++;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="app()">Add</button>
<div id="demo">
</div>
```

Comment: I dont understand why. Can you please explain?

Comment: You need to concatenate the "String" button to create a new element. if you use **=** you are replacing the "String"

Comment: you can remove the `j` variable, its not required there!

Comment: so why you don't edit it to get an up-vote from me? ;D (also its better to increase the i before adding to innerHTML to have first button as Btn1)

Comment: edit ;) (i didnt increase the i before because i dindt know what the user wants, but thx for the comment ;D)

Answer (score 0):

You need to append HTML

```
var s = 0;
function app(){
 s++;
 var strHTML = "<button>Btn"+ s+"</button>" 
 document.getElementById('test').insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', strHTML );
 }
```

See this http://jsfiddle.net/euQ5n/226/

Answer (score 0):

Or make it a little more readable.

```
<script>
var i = 0;
var j = "";

function makeButton(index) {
  var $button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
  $button.innerHTML = 'Button ' + index;
  $button.onclick = function() {
    alert('You clicked button:' + index);
  };

  return $button;
}

function onAddButtonClick() {
  document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(makeButton(i));
  i++; // increase number for next time;
}

</script>  

<button type="button" onclick="onAddButtonClick()">Add</button>

<div id="demo">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var i1 = 0;
function app1()
{
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 div.innerHTML = "<button type='button'>Btn " + (++i1) + "</button>";
 
 for (var child = 0; child < div.childNodes.length; child) {
  document.getElementById("demo1").append(div.childNodes[child]);
 }
}

var i2 = 0;

function app2() {
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += "<button type='button'>Btn " +
    ++i2 + "</button>";
}

var d1s = new Date().getTime();
for (var j1 = 0; j1 < 1000; j1++) {
 app2();
}
var d1e = new Date().getTime();

console.log((d1e - d1s) / 1000);

var d2s = new Date().getTime();
for (var j2 = 0; j2 < 1000; j2++) {
 app1();
}
var d2e = new Date().getTime();

console.log((d2e - d2s) / 1000);
```

```html
<div id="demo1"></div>

<div id="demo2"></div>
```

concatenation with innerHtml += is very slow